# Filter the first and current day of the month in R using lubridate and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to filter the current day of the month and the first day of the current month using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. For some odd reason I can't seem to filter the first day of the month correctly. I'm only able to extract the current day of the month (`Date == Sys.Date`). Can anyone point me in the right direction w.r.t what I'm doing wrong here?

```
data %>% filter(Date == floor_date(Sys.Date(), 'month') | Date == Sys.Date())
```

Here is my dataset (`data`)

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18122, 18123, 18124, 18127, 
18128, 18129, 18130, 18131, 18134, 18135, 18136, 18137, 18138, 
18141, 18142, 18143, 18144, 18145, 18148, 18149, 18150, 18151, 
18152, 18155, 18156, 18157, 18158, 18159, 18162, 18163, 18164, 
18165, 18166, 18169, 18170, 18171, 18172, 18173, 18176, 18177, 
18178, 18179, 18180, 18183, 18184, 18185, 18186, 18187, 18190, 
18191, 18192, 18193, 18194, 18197, 18198, 18199, 18200, 18201, 
18204, 18205, 18206, 18207, 18208, 18211, 18212, 18213, 18214, 
18215, 18218, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18222, 18225, 18226, 18227, 
18228, 18229, 18232, 18233, 18234, 18235, 18236, 18239, 18240, 
18241, 18242, 18243, 18246, 18247, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18253, 
18254, 18255, 18256, 18257, 18260, 18261, 18262, 18263, 18264, 
18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18274, 18275, 18276, 18277, 
18278, 18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18288, 18289, 18290, 
18291, 18292, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18302, 18303, 
18304, 18305, 18306, 18309, 18310, 18311, 18312, 18313, 18316, 
18317, 18318, 18319, 18320, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 
18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 
18341, 18344, 18345, 18346, 18347, 18348, 18351, 18352, 18353, 
18354, 18355, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18365, 18366, 
18367, 18368, 18369, 18372, 18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 18379, 
18380, 18381, 18382, 18383, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 
18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18400, 18401, 18402, 18403, 
18404, 18407, 18408, 18409, 18410, 18411, 18414, 18415, 18416, 
18417, 18418, 18421, 18422, 18423, 18424, 18425, 18428, 18429, 
18430, 18431, 18432, 18435, 18436, 18437, 18438, 18439, 18442, 
18443, 18444, 18445, 18446, 18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 
18456, 18457, 18458, 18459, 18460, 18463, 18464, 18465, 18466, 
18467, 18470, 18471, 18472, 18473, 18474, 18477, 18478, 18479, 
18480, 18481, 18484, 18485, 18486, 18487, 18488), class = "Date"), 
    `EUR-ZAR` = c(17.1786, 16.9625, 16.9623, 17.1039, 17.0507, 
    16.8403, 16.8875, 16.9746, 16.9281, 16.9701, 17.0584, 16.9336, 
    16.6856, 16.719, 16.5601, 16.3306, 16.4193, 16.3137, 16.3132, 
    16.1692, 16.1859, 16.1261, 16.26, 16.1303, 16.2788, 16.1964, 
    16.3505, 16.4145, 16.3684, 16.3783, 16.4091, 16.4073, 16.5648, 
    16.4901, 16.7468, 16.7416, 16.621, 16.5033, 16.659, 16.7383, 
    16.7151, 16.5305, 16.3349, 16.3382, 16.4232, 16.5415, 16.4949, 
    16.5309, 16.4403, 16.2323, 16.2857, 16.3008, 16.2053, 16.1522, 
    16.2455, 16.7019, 16.8317, 16.7727, 16.4713, 16.342, 16.3889, 
    16.2536, 16.3677, 16.4115, 16.4231, 16.4036, 16.3341, 16.2459, 
    16.3792, 16.3316, 16.3741, 16.2386, 16.2109, 16.2691, 16.3048, 
    16.2427, 16.1978, 16.1722, 16.1067, 16.2107, 16.1759, 16.2496, 
    16.1719, 16.2235, 16.4079, 16.3401, 16.1575, 16.1278, 15.9924, 
    16.0404, 15.8794, 15.8068, 15.7569, 15.7524, 15.7031, 15.7015, 
    15.6823, 15.683, 15.7949, 15.6952, 15.6954, 15.737, 15.9717, 
    15.9149, 15.927, 15.7244, 15.7906, 15.9698, 16.0174, 16.0041, 
    16.0309, 16.0453, 16.1067, 16.0693, 16.059, 15.8889, 15.9046, 
    15.9346, 16.0861, 16.0127, 16.0859, 16.2748, 16.6269, 16.4558, 
    16.3067, 16.2238, 16.3745, 16.4821, 16.3202, 16.153, 16.1417, 
    16.2009, 16.1346, 16.2243, 16.2009, 16.1816, 16.2811, 16.266, 
    16.435, 16.5702, 16.6372, 17.0262, 17.2752, 17.1897, 17.2145, 
    16.9919, 17.4742, 17.6835, 18.3893, 18.0364, 18.2503, 18.4685, 
    18.0732, 18.5828, 18.2228, 18.8339, 18.5551, 18.827, 19.1586, 
    18.9093, 18.8365, 19.0941, 19.6372, 19.7686, 19.7002, 19.9831, 
    20.0233, 20.529, 20.1498, 19.8547, 19.7523, 19.6939, 19.6433, 
    19.7405, 20.0944, 20.3403, 20.3123, 20.3716, 20.4052, 20.5847, 
    20.5481, 20.5899, 20.5908, 20.3126, 20.1226, 19.7388, 20.2724, 
    20.6856, 20.1678, 19.9391, 20.2879, 20.1205, 19.8757, 19.8851, 
    19.9789, 19.9776, 19.9183, 20.0801, 20.0039, 20.0225, 19.6641, 
    19.2638, 19.2479, 19.1915, 19.0982, 19.1326, 19.3731, 19.4937, 
    19.3221, 19.1704, 18.9994, 19.1692, 19.0316, 18.8152, 18.8407, 
    18.7749, 19.4258, 19.179, 19.3685, 19.3955, 19.3, 19.5502, 
    19.3765, 19.4864, 19.4518, 19.568, 19.2321, 19.3298, 19.4072, 
    19.4781, 19.156, 19.0789, 19.1227, 19.1907, 19.3441, 19.1941, 
    18.9958, 18.9444, 19.0857, 19.0556, 18.9132, 19.0699, 19.0625, 
    19.019, 18.9119, 19.0619, 19.3363, 19.4328, 19.3019, 19.3404, 
    19.4958, 19.8343, 20.0239, 20.2172, 20.486, 20.5646, 20.6937, 
    20.7893, 20.7693, 20.5407, 20.5476, 20.5847, 20.5583)), row.names = c(NA, 
-263L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Maybe because there's not the first date of the current month in the data frame in the first place. I don't see `2020-08-01`.

Comment: @xwhitelight oh makes sense, this is an automated dataset of currencies so I think its possible that ```2020-08-01``` was just not a trading day. Is there anyway I can tweak my code up to always return the earliest day of the month in my dataset (even if that's ```2020-08-02``` in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

todays_date <- Sys.Date()

data %>%
  filter(month(Date) == month(todays_date), year(Date) == year(todays_date)) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  slice(1L, n())
```

This first select current months data, `arrange` it based on `Date` and selects first and latest entry from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solutions .

say your dataframe name is `df`

```
df$DAY <- day(df$Date)

df1 <- subset(df,df$DAY=='1' | df$DAY == Sys.Date())
```